# How to change the tuning in guitar pro 5 but keep the original tuning displayed

Tags: guitar, tablature

I tune all the time in Eb , but I don't want the display of the notes in the fretboard to be in Eb, I want it to stay in E.
how do I do that please?

Answer (score 2):

When you open the tuning dialog, and choose your desired tuning, then just click "Keep the Fingering".

In this way, your tab notes will not be changed, but only the sound play.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Newer versions of Guitar Pro have an option called "shifted tuning impacts notation" (or something like that). This lets you use a "tune all strings a half-step down" tuning while keeping the notation written as if it were in standard notation.

If you can't update your version of Guitar Pro for whatever reason, I suggest checking out Soundslice, which [supports this out of the box](https://www.soundslice.com/blog/110/new-options-for-capo-and-shifted-guitar-tunings/) and is free to use.